# assigning value to a variable inside a jade file

Tags: pug

Is it possible to assign variables inside a jade file, in order to make the code more readable?

Specifically, I created this jade file:

```
extends layout
- var format = "%+1.0f"
block title
  title Your score table
block body
 ...
      td.utilityUtil #{sprintf(format,value)}
 ...
```

And got an error in the last line, that "format" is not defined. Probably I don't assign it correctly, but I didn't find the correct syntax.

P.S. I have Express 3.

Answer (score 25):

You have to declare the variable in the block scope :

```
extends layout
block title
title Your score table
block body
    - var format = "%+1.0f"
    ...
    td.utilityUtil #{sprintf(format,value)}
    ...
```

Comment: I don't know how it took me like an hour of experimentation and googling until I worked out this was the problem with my template, but thank you, so much. I only regret that I have but one like to give

Comment: What if you wanted to use the 'format' variable in the example across multiple blocks?