# jade: How to pass global variables in a block

Tags: pug

As in the object, I'm trying to pass a variable created by compiler inside a block:

```
| #{env} //output => prod
block scripts
  script(src= (env == 'prod' ? 'min' : 'scripts') + "/main.js")
```

Comment: here a solution that is not valid for global variables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010705/assigning-value-to-a-variable-inside-a-jade-file#14155873

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable.

```
block scripts
  - var src = (env == 'prod' ? 'min' : 'scripts') + "/main.js"
  script(src=src)
```